# Finding all simple cycles in undirected graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement a task of finding all simple cycles in undirected graph. Originally, the task was to find all cycles of fixed length (= 3), and I've managed to do it using the properties of adjacency matrices. But before using that approach I was also trying to use DFS and it worked correctly for really small input sizes, but for bigger inputs it was going crazy, ending with (nearly) infinite loops. I tried to fix the code, but then it just could not find all the cycles.

My code is attached below.

**1.** Please, do not pay attention to several global variables used. The working code using another approach was already submitted. This one is just for me to see if how to make DFS work properly.

**2.** Yes, I've searched for this problem before posting this question, but either the option I've managed to find used different approach, or it was just about detecting if there are cycles at all. Besides, I want to know if it is possible to fix **my** code.

Big thanks to anyone who could help.

```
num_res = 0
adj_list = []
cycles_list = []


def dfs(v, path):
    global num_res
    for node in adj_list[v]:
        if node not in path:
            dfs(node, path + [node])
        elif len(path) >= 3 and (node == path[-3]):
            if sorted(path[-3:]) not in cycles_list:
                cycles_list.append(sorted(path[-3:]))
                num_res += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_towns, num_pairs = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    adj_list = [[] for x in range(num_towns)]
    adj_matrix = [[0 for x in range(num_towns)] for x in range(num_towns)]

    # EDGE LIST TO ADJACENCY LIST
    for i in range(num_pairs):
        cur_start, cur_end = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
        adj_list[cur_start].append(cur_end)
        adj_list[cur_end].append(cur_start)

    dfs(0, [0])

    print(num_res)
```

UPD: Works ok for following inputs:

```
5 8
4 0
0 2
0 1
3 2
4 3
4 2
1 3
3 0
```

(output: 5)

```
6 15
5 4
2 0
3 1
5 1
4 1
5 3
1 0
4 0
4 3
5 2
2 1
3 0
3 2
5 0
4 2
```

(output: 20)

```
9 12
0 1
0 2
1 3
1 4
2 4
2 5
3 6
4 6
4 7
5 7
6 8
7 8
```

(output: 0)

Does NOT give any output and just continues through the loop.

```
22 141
5 0
12 9
18 16
7 6
7 0
4 1
16 1
8 1
6 1
14 0
16 0
11 9
20 14
12 3
18 3
1 0
17 0
17 15
14 5
17 13
6 5
18 12
21 1
13 4
18 11
18 13
8 0
15 9
21 18
13 6
12 8
16 13
20 18
21 3
11 6
15 14
13 5
17 5
10 8
9 5
16 14
19 9
7 5
14 10
16 4
18 7
12 1
16 3
19 18
19 17
20 2
12 11
15 3
15 11
13 2
10 7
15 13
10 9
7 3
14 3
10 1
21 19
9 2
21 4
19 0
18 1
10 6
15 0
20 7
14 11
19 6
18 10
7 4
16 10
9 4
13 3
12 2
4 3
17 7
15 8
13 7
21 14
4 2
21 0
20 16
18 8
20 12
14 2
13 1
16 15
17 11
17 16
20 10
15 7
14 1
13 0
17 12
18 5
12 4
15 1
16 9
9 1
17 14
16 2
12 5
20 8
19 2
18 4
19 4
19 11
15 12
14 12
11 8
17 10
18 14
12 7
16 8
20 11
8 7
18 9
6 4
11 5
17 6
5 3
15 10
20 19
15 6
19 10
20 13
9 3
13 9
13 10
21 7
19 13
19 12
19 14
6 3
21 15
21 6
17 3
10 5
```

(output should be 343)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "nearly infinite" loop. It's either infinite or finite. I'd also recommend to add the test case your code is failing to the question.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I just meant that I don't know if the loop is actually infinite or it will stop in some time.